# How to get grads in pytorch after matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to get the product of matrix multiplication in the latent space and optimize the weight matrix by the optimizer. I use different kinds of ways to do that. While, The value of 'pi_' in the below codes never changes. What should I do?

I've tried different functions to get the product, like torch.mm(), torch.matual() and @. The weight matrix 'pi_' never changed.

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
#from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST

def get_mnist(data_dir='./data/mnist/',batch_size=128):
    train=MNIST(root=data_dir,train=True,download=True)
    test=MNIST(root=data_dir,train=False,download=True)

    X=torch.cat([train.data.float().view(-1,784)/255.,test.data.float().view(-1,784)/255.],0)
    Y=torch.cat([train.targets,test.targets],0)

    dataset=dict()
    dataset['X']=X
    dataset['Y']=Y

    dataloader=DataLoader(TensorDataset(X,Y),batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)

    return dataloader

class tests(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(tests, self).__init__()

        self.pi_= torch.nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(10, 1).fill_(1),requires_grad=True)
        self.linear0 = torch.nn.Linear(784,10)
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(1,784)

    def forward(self, data):
        data = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.linear0(data))
#        data = data.mm(self.pi_)
#        data = torch.mm(data, self.pi_)
#        data = data @ self.pi_
        data = torch.matmul(data, self.pi_)
        data = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.linear1(data))
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DL=get_mnist()
    t = tests().cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(t.parameters(), lr = 2e-3)

    for i in range(100):
        for inputs, classes in DL:
            inputs = inputs.cuda()

            res = t(inputs)    
            loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(res, inputs)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        print("Epoch:", i,"pi:",t.pi_)
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
You have too many parameters in your neural network, some of them becomes useless and therefore they are no longer being updated. Change your network architecture to reduce useless parameters.

**Full explanation:**
The weight matrix `pi_` does change. You initialize `pi_` as all `1`, after running the first epochs, the weight matrix `pi_` becomes

```
output >>>
tensor([[0.9879],
        [0.9874],
        [0.9878],
        [0.9880],
        [0.9876],
        [0.9878],
        [0.9878],
        [0.9873],
        [0.9877],
        [0.9871]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```

So, it has changed once. The true reason behind it involves some mathematics. But to put it in non-mathematical ways it means this layer doesn't contribute much to the loss, therefore, the network decided not to update this layer. i.e. The existence of `pi_` in this network is redundant.

If you want to observe the change in `pi_`, you should modify the neural network such that `pi_` is not redundant anymore.

One possible modification is to change your reconstruction problem to a classification problem

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset
#from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST

def get_mnist(data_dir='./data/mnist/',batch_size=128):
    train=MNIST(root=data_dir,train=True,download=True)
    test=MNIST(root=data_dir,train=False,download=True)

    X=torch.cat([train.data.float().view(-1,784)/255.,test.data.float().view(-1,784)/255.],0)
    Y=torch.cat([train.targets,test.targets],0)

    dataset=dict()
    dataset['X']=X
    dataset['Y']=Y

    dataloader=DataLoader(TensorDataset(X,Y),batch_size=batch_size,shuffle=True)

    return dataloader

class tests(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(tests, self).__init__()

#         self.pi_= torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn((10, 1),requires_grad=True))
        self.pi_= torch.nn.Parameter(torch.FloatTensor(10, 1).fill_(1),requires_grad=True)
        self.linear0 = torch.nn.Linear(784,10)
#         self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(1,784)

    def forward(self, data):
        data = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.linear0(data))
#        data = data.mm(self.pi_)
#        data = torch.mm(data, self.pi_)
#        data = data @ self.pi_
        data = torch.matmul(data, self.pi_)
#         data = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.linear1(data))
        return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DL=get_mnist()
    t = tests().cuda()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(t.parameters(), lr = 2e-3)

    for i in range(100):
        for inputs, classes in DL:
            inputs = inputs.cuda()
            classes = classes.cuda().float()
            output = t(inputs)    
            loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(output.view(-1), classes)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
#         print("Epoch:", i, "pi_grad", t.pi_.grad)
        print("Epoch:", i,"pi:",t.pi_)
```

Now, `pi_` changes every single epoch.

```
output >>>
Epoch: 0 pi: Parameter containing:
tensor([[1.3429],
        [1.0644],
        [0.9817],
        [0.9767],
        [0.9715],
        [1.1110],
        [1.1139],
        [0.9759],
        [1.2424],
        [1.2632]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 1 pi: Parameter containing:
tensor([[1.4413],
        [1.1977],
        [0.9588],
        [1.0325],
        [0.9241],
        [1.1988],
        [1.1690],
        [0.9248],
        [1.2892],
        [1.3427]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 2 pi: Parameter containing:
tensor([[1.4653],
        [1.2351],
        [0.9539],
        [1.1588],
        [0.8670],
        [1.2739],
        [1.2058],
        [0.8648],
        [1.2848],
        [1.3891]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
Epoch: 3 pi: Parameter containing:
tensor([[1.4375],
        [1.2256],
        [0.9580],
        [1.2293],
        [0.8174],
        [1.3471],
        [1.2035],
        [0.8102],
        [1.2505],
        [1.4201]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```